# Using a variable for a column name in a db query

Tags: database, matlab

How do I retrieve data in matlab database using column name (where clause)? I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
catgQuery = strcat('select ID from MyTable where ColumnName= ', Category);
catgCurs = exec(conn,catgQuery);
catgResult = fetch(catgCurs);
r1 = catgResult.data
```

Comment: From the docs I would say you could do r1 = fetch(conn, catgQuery). http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.fetch.html have you tried that?

Comment: When i tried what u suggested, it gave me the following error:

Error using database/fetch (line 37)
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Error in displayMain (line 36)
    r1 = fetch(conn,catgQuery)

Comment: So, `ColumnName` the name of a particular column in the DB, is it?

Comment: yes and Category is a variable which contains some value

Comment: Maybe you need to put quotes around category? `catgQuery = strcat('select ID from MyTable where ColumnName= ''', Category, '''');`

Comment: This works!!!! Thank you sooo much!! I've been working on it from the past 4 hours!! Thank you!!! :D

Comment: No problem, I'm going to post it as a solution for future searchers and so that you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around `category`

```
catgQuery = strcat('select ID from MyTable where ColumnName= ''', Category, '''');
```